# Use a filter to query a list with only child entity conditions EF Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core

This works fine. But how do I customize the conditions for adding filters?input is the value entered by the user

```cs
var resultList = dbContext.BuyerBill
                 .Include(x=>x.BuyerBillItems.Where(x=>x.Status == input.Status && x.BuildTime > input.BeginTime && x.BuildTime < input.EndTime))
                 .ToList();
```

the way I want:

```cs
var query = WhereIf(input.Status!=null,x=>x.Status == input.Status);
query = WhereIf(input.BeginTime!=null,x=>x.BuildTime > input.BeginTime);
query = WhereIf(input.EndTime!=null,x=>x.BuildTime > input.EndTime);
```

this is my entity

```cs
public class BuyerBill
{
    public BuyerBill()
    {
        BuyerBillItems = new List<BuyerBillItems>();
    }
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int BuyUserId {get;set;}
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    public List<BuyerBillItems> BuyerBillItems { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class BuyerBillItems
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int BuyerBillId {get;set;}
    public decimal Fee {get;set;}
    public int Status {get;set;}
    public dateTime CreateTime {get;set;}
    public BuyerBill BuyerBill {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

1、If the user does not select the time query

```
Select * from BuyerBill as buy inner join BuyerBillItems As item On buy.Id=item.BuyerBillId 
                          where item.Status=1
```

2、If the user selects the time query

```
Select * from BuyerBill as buy inner join BuyerBillItems as item on buy.Id=item.BuyerBillId 
                            where item.Status=1 and item.BuildTime > '2022-7-19' and item.BuildTime < '2022-7-19'
```

How to use efcore to implement the SQL conditions I described?

Mainly, I want to filter sub entities according to conditions. If there is only one entity, I know Where() method can be used for filtering, but I don't know how to use conditional filtering for sub entities

---

I solved the above problem with LinqKit, but now I have a new problem。

```
 var predicatess = PredicateBuilder.New<BuyerBillItems>(true);
            predicatess = predicatess.And(x => x.CreateTime > StringHelper.AddDateTime("2022-07-16"));
            predicatess = predicatess.And(x => x.Status == 2);
            //I'm dumb and this line of code seems redundant. But I don't know how to convert implicitly
            var convertPredicate = (Expression<Func<BuyerBillItems, bool>>)predicatess;

            var query = dbContext.BuyerBill.AsExpandable().Include(x => x.BuyerBillItems.Where(x => convertPredicate.Invoke(x)))
                .Where(x => x.BuyerBillItems.Any(s => convertPredicate.Invoke(s)))
                .Where(x => x.BuyUserId == 4);

            //If you don't use Select, everything is normal
            var result1 = query.ToList();

            //BuyerBillItemsDto result is incorrect after using Select
            var result2 = query.Select(x => new BuyerBillDto
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                BuyUserId = x.BuyUserId,
                OrderId = x.OrderId,
                BuyerBillItemsDto = mapper.Map<List<BuyerBillItems>, List<BuyerBillItemsDto>>(x.BuyerBillItems)
            }).ToList();
```

I have to use select to filter the columns to avoid performance loss

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding - could you post sample in- and output

Comment: As usual: build the predicate with a predicate builder.

Comment: Thank you for replying to me, I have updated the detailed description

Comment: If you use `Select` - you can remove `Include`. So you are on the start of the problem.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv Can you help me, this problem has been bothering me for two days

Comment: I tried to put the filter condition of BuyerBillItems in Select, but an exception occurred：The query has been configured to use 'QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery' and contains a collection in the 'Select' call, which could not be split into separate query. Please remove 'AsSplitQuery' if applied or add 'AsSingleQuery' to the query

Comment: Without Automapper it is easy.

Comment: I can do without Automapper, as long as the query results are correct

Answer (score 0):

Curently you cannot use own extensions in `Include` body. So, consider to write query in the following way:

```cs
var resultList = dbContext.BuyerBill
    .Include(x => x.BuyerBillItems.Where(x => 
        (input.Status == null || x.Status == input.Status && x.BuildTime > input.BeginTime && x.BuildTime < input.EndTime)) &&
        (input.BeginTime == null || x.BuildTime > input.BeginTime) &&
        (input.EndTime == null || x.BuildTime > input.EndTime)
    )
    .ToList();
```

**Update based on updated reuiqrements**

For fully custom projection, there is not needed to build `Include`, because `Select` specifies which data is needed to retrieve from database.

Query can be rewritten using `WhereIf` extension:

```cs
var result = dbContext.BuyerBill
    .Select(b => new BuyerBillDto
    {
        Id = b.Id,
        BuyUserId = b.BuyUserId,
        OrderId = b.OrderId,
        BuyerBillItemsDto = b.BuyerBillItems
            .AsQueryable()
            .WhereIf(input.Status != null, x => x.Status == input.Status)
            .WhereIf(input.BeginTime != null, x => x.BuildTime > input.BeginTime)
            .WhereIf(input.EndTime != null, x => x.BuildTime > input.EndTime)
            .Select(item => new BuyerBillItemsDto
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                // other properties
            })
            .ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I implemented the extension with LinqKit, but now I have a new problem.The description of the problem I modified the article

Comment: I know LINQKit very well, show me how you implemented this extension.

Comment: I'm new to this, I solved it using the PredicateBuilder class, I don't know if this counts as an extension

Comment: Ok, that's fine.

Comment: @john, updated answer.

Comment: I tested your answer and found that it is still abnormal because I configured split query：  The query has been configured to use 'QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery' and contains a collection in the 'Select' call, which could not be split into separate query. Please remove 'AsSplitQuery' if applied or add 'AsSingleQuery' to the query

Comment: Update to EF Core 6, EF Core 5 cannot split custom projection.

Comment: Or add  `.AsSingleQuery()` to the end of the query.

Comment: My project is .NET 5.0, I may take a while to update to .NET 6 before trying to update EFCORE to 6.0

Comment: Well, `AsSplitQuery` may help, but it may slowdown this query. So maybe better to use `Include` variant without `Select` and project to DTO after materialization.